# magento error in internet explorer mage.cookies.path = '/'; 'mage' is undefined

Tags: internet-explorer, magento-1.7, undefined

I am getting this error on my magento website.  It is magento version 1.7.2.  It will not let customers add any products to the cart when they are using internet explorer 7 8 or 9.  I have not tested it on other versions of ie.  Please help, this is driving me crazy.  I have already made sure that these are in this order.

I have done the suggestion below and it does not work!

In order to solve this issues you need to be sure that in head.phtml

> app/design/frontend/base/default/template/page/html/head.phtml

you have

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml() ?>
```

after

```
<?php echo $this->getCssJsHtml() ?>.
```

So it should look like:

```
<?php echo $this->getCssJsHtml() ?>

<?php echo $this->getChildHtml() ?>
```